# Symfony 2.0 and REST

Tags: php, rest, symfony

What are the best practices for using REST with Symfony 2.0.  I've found various questions on SO that discuss Symfony 1.4 (and lower), but nothing for 2.0.

Comment: Symfony2 has no best practices for REST.

Comment: Is this the answer?  http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would look into the [FOSREstBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle). It is full of best practices for combining Symfony2 and REST. It also makes the process of developing a REST API in Symfony quite painless.

Comment: I wrote something a few weeks ago: http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/. I hope it could be useful.

Comment: @WilliamDURAND That url is broken for me. It looks like it should now be http://williamdurand.fr/PHP/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/.